# Is there a convention registers to use for base and index?

Tags: assembly, x86

The memory addressing general form is:

```
[base + index*scale + disp]
```

Technically any register can be the `base`. And any register can be the `index` (except `esp`).

But is there a convention registers to use for `base` and `index`? I suppose that `ebx` (base register) is used for the `base`, but what about the `index`?

Answer (score 2):

> I suppose that ebx (base register) is used for the base

Not really.

In 16-bit code not all registers could be used as "base". `BX` was one of the few registers that could be used. Therefore that register was called "base register".

However in 32-bit code there is no such limitation.

> Is there a convention

Conventions are only needed if different pieces of codes must be written the same way.

Example: If one assembler file contains a sub-function and another assembler file contains code calling that sub-function the programmers of both files must use the same registers to pass function arguments.

Because this is not the case here no convention is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The point of having this much flexibility is that you can avoid using extra `mov` instructions to put pointers and indices into specific registers.

Just use data in whatever registers are most convenient.  e.g. in 32-bit code, use one of the registers that the calling convention you're using allows you to use without saving/restoring.  (Typically EAX, ECX, and EDX).

If there are no other factors, keeping destination pointers in edi/rdi 
 and source pointers in esi/rsi is sensible, since that's what the D and S mean in the register names.  It helps you remember what registers you're using for what, but the hardware doesn't care (unless you want to use `rep movsd` for a block copy).